# Godot - Video Player frozen on launch

Tags: godot, gdscript

Good Morning Everyone,

I'm trying to use Godot for a very simple app.

```
Open to start screen with a looping video.
  If button 1 is pressed, change scene, start video 2, return to start at end of video 2
  If button 2 is pressed, ^ for video 3
```

I'm using WebM as my video sources. Sizes are 14.6 MB, 36.8 MB, 37.4 MB.
I have autoplay selected.

However, the video is frozen on frame 1 and no audio plays. the log prints True for is_playing()

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Godot WebM support had many of issues, ranging from slow performance to crashes. Consequently it has been removed for Godot 4.0 to reduce maintenance cost ([read more](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/53833)). Whether or not it will make a return as an official plugin is yet to be determined, but some kind of plugin is likely to be the path forward for WebM support in Godot.

Although Godot 3.x may still get WebM patches. I would encourage to convert the video to OGV. There are plenty of free tool that can do this conversion.